# Is it possible to parse JSON data of one complex object to custom object via API

Tags: java, android, json

I have a web project with 2 Java Entities(Lets Say E1,E2) like how mybatis and VO works.

Object structure:

```
class E1{
   String a;
    .... n other data members
   E2 e2;
}
class E2{
   String b;
   .... n other data members
}
```

Is it possible to make a single class in Android project, i.e.

```
class E1 {
    String a;
    String b; //This Data member belongs to class E2
}
```

and parse it with the help of a framework (like Jackson) or I have to write a custom class for that?

My JSON Data will look like this:

```
{
"E1": {
    "a": "some data",
    .
    .
    .
    "E2": {
        "b": "some data",
        .
        .
        other data
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any API which can do this?
I asked this because with my web Application its not just 2 Class but atleast 10 interconnected class and I am not Using them in my android app. So don't wanna replicate the same classes in android app.

Also if you can suggest any other possible way.

Comment: Do you want to create one class for all types of objects in your json?

Comment: @MichaelSpitsin no but for a particular view

Comment: Why don't you want to just create two classes E1 and E2 then get json string and pass it to Jackson's objectMapper?

Comment: because as I said Its not just 2 classes it is just an example. My entity is way more complex then this

Comment: In general you have 2 possibilities: use some sort of map (java Map, JsonObject or JsonArray, or library Trees, like JsonTree), or use plain java objects. In second way you will need to create class for each Json object and then pass them to objectMapp or gson, or whatever. Of course you can combine those two variants

Answer (score 0):

It would be a very **bad** design practice/approach, making things very difficult to debug, error prone and not future proof (think about it, what if you add to one of the 10 classes a field that conflict with another class' field?).

Anyway, if you still want to trick your way out of the correct approach that would be to have 10 classes, I am not aware of any lib that provides you with this feature. You could parse json ==> 10 Java [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), then merge the 10  [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) through the [`Map::putAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map)) method and finally pass the obtained [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) that contains all the objects to Jackson.

Comment: Yes I thought about the same thing. researched, and didn't got any good method. So had to come here

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use @JsonAnySetter annotation from Jackson library on the receiver POJO.

```
public class E1{
    public String a;
    private Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getParamMap() {
        return paramMap;
    }
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setParamMap(String s, Object o) {
        paramMap.put(s, o);
    }
}
```

This will put every unimplemented attributes in a HashMap.

In combination with @JsonAnyGetter, the serialization of the receiver POJO will give the same result as the JSON input.